# fail2ban fails to add iptables to rules

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, fail2ban, ufw

I'm having issues with fail2ban is not adding the banned IP to iptables.

this is the error;

```
2022-01-29 15:13:48,499 fail2ban.actions        [2608]: NOTICE  [man] Restore Ban 212.192.246.26
2022-01-29 15:13:48,513 fail2ban.utils          [2608]: ERROR   7f9281692660 -- exec: iptables -w -N f2b-man
iptables -w -A f2b-man -j RETURN
iptables -w -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports all -j f2b-man
2022-01-29 15:13:48,514 fail2ban.utils          [2608]: ERROR   7f9281692660 -- stderr: 'iptables: Chain already exists.'
2022-01-29 15:13:48,514 fail2ban.utils          [2608]: ERROR   7f9281692660 -- stderr: "iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): invalid port/service `all' specified"
2022-01-29 15:13:48,514 fail2ban.utils          [2608]: ERROR   7f9281692660 -- stderr: "Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information."
2022-01-29 15:13:48,514 fail2ban.utils          [2608]: ERROR   7f9281692660 -- returned 2
2022-01-29 15:13:48,514 fail2ban.actions        [2608]: ERROR   Failed to execute ban jail 'man' action 'iptables-multiport' info 'ActionInfo({'ip': '212.192.246.26', 'family': 'inet4', 'fid': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7f9280d62e50>, 'raw-ticket': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7f9280d63550>})': Error starting action Jail('man')/iptables-multiport: 'Script error'
```

so iptables don't like;

```
iptables -w -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports all -j f2b-man
```

--dport **all**  is apparently the issue,so my question is Why?
why is fail2ban giving an faulty command, and how to correct it?

edit: running Ubuntu server 20.04.3 without netplan.

Comment: It's a problem with your fail2ban configuration, that you need to show us. There is somewhere an incorrect `all` value for `port`  when iptables expects something like `0:65535`.

Comment: @Chris yeah, I suspected that, but in what config are you specifying that? there are like 30 different .conf files

Comment: It seems to be related to the jail `man` so first this part in your `jail.local` (or `jail.conf` if modified directly), Then all other customizations you made to `action`  and `action-multiports`

Comment: @Chris I've not made any customizations, except added a filter for ufwprobing..  I actually checked the man, and  it said port = any,  I changed it to 0:65535, and it stopped to complain, but it created this rule ‘f2b-man    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 0:65535‘ in the table input chain (policy drop) .. but no ip.. I think it's better to purge everything, and download the latest fail2ban and make a clean install

Comment: is fail2ban reading both jail.conf and jail.local or only jail.local if it exists?

Comment: fail2ban reads jail.conf first, then jail.local if exists. Properties you set in the local version overwrites the first, other are unchanged. Concerning iptables, the rule you show is normal. Its a reference to another chain (f2b-man) that *should* contain the ip.

Comment: @Chris  yeah, sudo iptables -S revealed the ip.. didn't see it when I listed the tables.. I guess it just didn't display those.. but I've seen more jails that had port  = all, I better change them to 0:65536 so they won't be any issues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action `iptables-multiport` is not really suitable to ban for all ports, there are other banning actions you can use instead.

Simply set `banaction` for the jail to all-ports action of your choice (for instance `iptables-allports`), or use [interpolation variable "banaction_allports"](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/6966b7e37d364b0fc3cac17537a09682dd2c9284/config/jail.conf#L209) already available in `jail.conf` (also set or overridden by your distribution maintainer), which could be also set in default section of your `jail.local`.

```
[man]
# banaction = iptables-allports
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s

[other-allports-jail]
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
```

Comment: so if I want all jails to ban all ports, I should set `[banaction = %(banaction_allports)s` under **[DEFAULT]**, and then not specify any banaction under each jail?

Comment: @AdamLarsson Yes, indeed.. or alternative change the `action =  ` which should then use `%(banaction_allports)s`, but you won't receive an email then.